# Unable to resolve plugin in Gradle Script plugin (external Gradle file)

Tags: gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to DRY some of the JFrog publishing code from my `build.gradle` to an external file (the Gradle Script plugin) (which I was duplicating in different Gradle projects).

https://github.com/wizpanda/gradle-common/blob/06a497b62fb4bb86facd96375bad1d91a67545d1/grails-plugin-jfrog-publish.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.21.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

publishing {
    publications {
        wpJFrogMaven(MavenPublication) {

            // Code removed for brevity 

        }
    }
}

// Code removed for brevity
```

I'm using this Gradle script plugin at the end of my main `build.gradle` of my actual project-

```
apply from: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wizpanda/gradle-common/main/grails-plugin-jfrog-publish.gradle"
```

When I run any Gradle task like- `./gradlew artifactoryPublish`, it fails with the error-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wizpanda/gradle-common/06a497b62fb4bb86facd96375bad1d91a67545d1/grails-plugin-jfrog-publish.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' not found.
```

But if I define the same `buildscript` configuration and plugins in the main `build.gradle` file of the project, it works fine.

I already spent 3-4 hours debugging it and read various articles, blogs and documentations-

- https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
- [Gradle with artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388533/gradle-with-artifactory/31389084)
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14517
- [When using custom Gradle plugin :Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010411/when-using-custom-gradle-plugin-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configur)
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:using_methods
- [Android Gradle remote scripts using 'apply from:' what does it do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652921/android-gradle-remote-scripts-using-apply-from-what-does-it-do)
- [https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#:~:text=Script%20plugins%20are%20automatically%20resolved,applied%20to%20a%20given%20target](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#:%7E:text=Script%20plugins%20are%20automatically%20resolved,applied%20to%20a%20given%20target).
- (Example) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle
- [How to load Gradle Plugin (with its depenecies) into build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081926/how-to-load-gradle-plugin-with-its-depenecies-into-build-gradle)
- [Access classpath dependencies defined in buildscript block in applied external-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058780/access-classpath-dependencies-defined-in-buildscript-block-in-applied-external-s)
- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-include-buildscript-block-from-external-gradle-script/7016
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html?_ga=2.152768569.1473794243.1621063281-1685601076.1621063281

Any stupid thing am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately third party plugins can not be transitively applied in the external Gradle script plugin if you reference it by ID.

You will have to reference the plugin by the implementation-class instead.

There is an [open ticket regarding this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1262).

You can see necessary changes in [following PR](https://github.com/wizpanda/gradle-common/pull/1).

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```

into

```
apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
```

Comment: Thank you so much, RenatoIvancic for X + 1 (for raising a PR). 50+ for that!

Answer (score 1):

Apply by id is not supported inside external build script. An alternative:

```
apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
```

[Plugin properties](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.jfrog.artifactory.properties#L16)

Comment: Bloody awesome, I read this many years back. But I was not able to recall the phrase

Comment: See, I fixed this myself in 2019 https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/pull/64/files#diff-4419737aa2b6937e7d473c0aeac480862903ef67e9d344a5ca4037b3827b1cefR24 

Comment: Thanks for the additional link of plugin properties. That helped me understanding!